# Static classes/fields. How often are you using it?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Sometimes it's very difficult to find an error in an application because of static data. Is it a good approach to use static data in OOP or is it better to avoid it?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

How often are you using static classes and for what purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking `static` methods leads to code that is hard to test since

- we cannot know if any other class have altered a possible state,
- we cannot easily mock or switch out a static implementation.

There are a few valid use cases though.

- To implement a Singleton pattern
- To provide costructional logic (e.g., *named* factory methods), such as

  - [Lists.newArrayList()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28%29)
  - [Lists.newArrayListWithExpectedSize()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28%29)
    An example of the latter could be

I would *normally* refrain from using `static` methods and let the default principle be that the existence of any `static` content needs to be motivated.

As pointed out by @Louis, `static` variables are useful to provide single instance constants. Typically this can also apply to member variables holding objects such as a Logger.

Comment: Static constants are all right, too, so long as they're genuinely immutable.

Comment: I'm also perfectly fine with stateless static methods: `Math.sqrt`, for example.  But the OP seemed to refer to "static data," which I assumed implied "there is state."

Answer (score 1):

Static should not be overused but it is worth in some situations, you should use static methods to provide factory methods or helper methods that have not direct relation to the instance object.

The static approach it is worth each time that you want to do an action or represent data that is related to the class and not to the object instance, so the approach of using static should not be avoided at all, but used only when it is really needed .

As in the most situations *there is not an absolute answer to your question* (avoid or not the use of static), *it depends on the context* , however you should not abuse of static ...